# Help with countdown jquery script to accept unix timestamp as input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I try to modify the keith-wood countdown timer to accept a *future unix timestamp* and hide the days.

To *hide the days* you use `$('#noDays').countdown({until: liftoffTime, format: 'HMS'});` as the example at http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html under the tab *Formats1* says.

I didn't manage yet to make it work. How to modify the code to get a *unix timestamp* as input and *hide the days*?

**Standard timer**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});

</script>
```

**My try to have as input a unix timestamp** (does not work)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(<?php echo $unixtimestamp; ?>*1000);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setTime()` function:

```
var austDay = new Date();
austDay.setTime(<?php echo $unixtimestamp * 1000; ?>);
```

**Edit:** added `* 1000` to go from unix timestamp to javascript timestamp...

Comment: I tried it with no result but when I added `*1000` it worked.

Comment: @JPampos Oops, sorry, you're right, unix timestamps are in seconds and javascript timestamps are in milliseconds...

Comment: Thanks for this, I managed to fix the second part from your reply.